# How to get system password from System.getProperties()

Tags: java

System.getProperties() return me all the System properties.

I can see my system user name in `user.name` property.

Is there a way to get something like `user.password`?

Note: *I have no intention to hack a system* :)

Comment: *"I have no intention to hack a system"* - and you no doubt have said the same thing if you had intended to :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the password is not stored as plain text in any of the OS now. Using System.getProperties you can get the following but not the password.

```
Key                 Meaning
"file.separator"    Character that separates components of a file path. This is "/" on UNIX and "\" on Windows.
"java.class.path"   Path used to find directories and JAR archives containing class files. Elements of the class path are separated by a platform-specific character specified in the path.separator property.
"java.home"         Installation directory for Java Runtime Environment (JRE)
"java.vendor"       JRE vendor name
"java.vendor.url"   JRE vendor URL
"java.version"      JRE version number
"line.separator"    Sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files
"os.arch"           Operating system architecture
"os.name"           Operating system name
"os.version"        Operating system version
"path.separator"    Path separator character used in java.class.path
"user.dir"          User working directory
"user.home"         User home directory
"user.name"         User account name
```

[Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot do that. The password isn't available as a system property.

I think the password is probably not stored as readable text anywhere in the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass in a password to your program, you can script it from the outside and "pass it in" when you run your program like this:

```
java -Dpassword=foo -jar myjar.jar
```

Calling System.getProperty("password") should then return "foo".

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

An OS isn't even required to use a password to authenticate the user. It could use finger prints, certificates etc.

And even if it uses a password to authenticate a user, it will probably not keep it memory.

Look for "single sign-on", if this is what you're after.

Comment: +1 for single sign on. This thread might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173704/which-sso-framework-to-use

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no `user.password` in Java System Property.

More : [System Properties](http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm)