# Passing windows credentials programmatically

Tags: java, windows, credentials

I have a VB script to which I need to pass username and password.

I want to run this VB script through Java code programmatically.

Is there a way that I can pass the Windows credentials to the VB script in Java programmatically?

Comment: Is the VB Script being executed via something `Runtime.exec()`?

Comment: yes, I plan to run it using Runtime.exec()

Comment: Can't you pass them as arguments during the Runtime.exec call?

Comment: This question will give you a good idea what kinds of information about the current user from Java http://stackoverflow.com/q/14997483/16959 unfortunately the password is not something you can extract from a running system.  You need to prompt for it

Comment: I don't want user interaction/input from user. And this code would run on different user machines

Comment: Thanks fro the link..Went through it..seems there is no way to do so. Getting it from the user seems only the way out

Answer (score -1):

You can have the credentials on the OS environment and read them from there:

```
String credentials = System.getenv().get("encrypted_credentials_or_something");
```

And then run your command from Java. However, Runtime.exec() won't work in some cases:

- When the command is not on the System's PATH
- When arguments are involved
- When you want to have access to the process output
- When you need to be able to kill the process
- When you need to check if it terminated successfully or in error (status code != 0 - which is why you write System.exit(int) to terminate a Java application. The System.exit(1), for example, indicates abnormal termination)

That's why I created this utility class to execute external processes with arguments and everything. It works very well for me:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ExternalCommandHelper {

    public static final void executeProcess(File directory, String command) throws Exception {
        InputStreamReader in = null;
        try {
            //creates a ProcessBuilder with the command and its arguments
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(extractCommandWithArguments(command));
            //errors will be printed to the standard output 
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            //directory from where the command will be executed
            builder.directory(directory);

            //starts the process
            Process pid = builder.start();

            //gets the process output so you can print it if you want
            in = new InputStreamReader(pid.getInputStream());

            //simply prints the output while the process is being executed
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            int status = 0;
            //waits for the process to finish. Expects status 0 no error. Throws exception if the status code is anything but 0.
            if ((status = pid.waitFor()) != 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Error executing " + command + " in " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + ". Error code: " + status);
            }

        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        }
    }

    //Splits the command and arguments. A bit more reliable than using String.split() 
    private static String[] extractCommandWithArguments(String command) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(command);
        String[] cmdWithArgs = new String[st.countTokens()];

        for (int i = 0; st.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
            cmdWithArgs[i] = st.nextToken();
        }
        return cmdWithArgs;
    }
}
```